# How to render html content with jinja using flask?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask in an app that render some data from a sqlite database. My problem is when the app render some text that has html inside, appear as text instead of html. For example, the record in database has the following text:

```
My tailor <strong>is</strong> rich
```

The html page render as is:

```
<html>
<!-- snip .... -->
My tailor &gt;strong&lt;is&gt;/strong&lt; rich
<!-- snip .... -->
</html>
```

And, what I want is this ("is" word has to be bolder):

```
<html>
<!-- snip .... -->
My tailor <strong>is</strong> rich
<!-- snip .... -->
</html>
```

Does anybody know how can I do that?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you know the content is safe, simply use the [`safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#safe) filter:

```
{# In the Jinja template #}
{% for article in articles %}
<div class="article">{{article|safe}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use jinja Markup class, just the way safe filter does. This will allow you to render HTML without filtering content through the safe filter. Below is an example of how this can be accomplished.

```
from jinja2 import Markup, escape

def render_markup():
    return Markup("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}".format(
        escape("My tailor "), 
        "<strong>", 
        escape("is"), 
        "</strong>", 
        escape(" rich")))
```

After this you can register your function in the Flask jinja globals, and use it from the jinja template.

```
app.jinja_env.globals["render_markup"] = render_markup
```

No safe needed in the template.

```
<html>
<!-- snip .... -->
{{ render_markup() }}
<!-- snip .... -->
</html>
```

Comment: Heh, just a somewhat silly example of how to format even sillier string, and properly use escape function :)

Comment: Thanks for letting that example anyway ;)